# usage of XSD in fixing errors in xml?

Tags: xml

I am just wondering if we can make XSD to fix the errors it finds in the xml itself rather than reporting them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, XSD describes the structural rules for a document.

**XSLT or XQuery would be more appropriate tools fix errors found in the XML.**